# why is my SelectMany linq statement consuming large amounts of memory

Tags: c#, linq, out-of-memory

I have a recursive function that hashes a directory and all sub directories.  I'm using SHA1 but that isn't the issue.  My issue is that it requires a byte array (understandably).  so i take my byte array list `List<byte[]> byteFile` and flatten it with a `bytfile.selectmany(x=>x).toarry()`.  The issue comes in when i flatten my array because in VS debugging i get an out of memory exception.  before the flattening the program in consuming approx 220KB.  after the flattening (when not running in the vs environment) the programming is consuming 1.09GB.  Why does flattening this list of byte arrays consume so much memory?  How can I reduce my memory footprint.

Here is the code i'm using

```
    private static byte[] GetGameHash(string path)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        List<byte[]> byteFile = new List<byte[]>();

        var dirs = dir.EnumerateDirectories();
        ReadFolderContents(dir, ref byteFile);

        //byte[] input = byteFile.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();

        SHA1 mSha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        mSha1.Initialize();
        byte[] hash = mSha1.ComputeHash(byteFile.SelectMany(x=>x).ToArray());
        mSha1.Dispose();

        byteFile.Clear();

        return hash;
    }

    private static void ReadFolderContents(DirectoryInfo directory, ref List<byte[]> files)
    {
        var dirFiles = directory.EnumerateFiles();
        foreach (var file in dirFiles)
            files.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName));


        var directories = directory.EnumerateDirectories();
        foreach (var dir in directories)
            ReadFolderContents(dir, ref files);
    }
```

Comment: ReadFolderContents() reads all the files into memory under that folder, if you have many files in the folder, it will use a lot of memory.

Comment: Presuming this code works (albeit inefficiently), you may have better luck asking someone to review on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 7):

The program as shown takes the entire contents of all the files in all the directories and puts it into a byte array. If you have a billion bytes of files, you'll get a billion byte array.

This is a terrible way to solve this problem.  If you're trying to hash something that is more than a tiny number of bytes, you should be hashing the stream, not the bytes.

Take a step back. What problem are you *really* trying to solve with this hashing? Let's concentrate on the real problem here; odds are good there is something more fundamentally wrong with your strategy here than merely the fact that it is running out of memory.

That said, there are a great many other problems with this short program you've written. Why call `Dispose` directly instead of using `using`, as would be idiomatic? Why are you using `ref`? Lists are already reference types.  Why is `bytefile` cleared immediately before it goes out of scope? Why are you realizing this as a list in the first place when it appears that all you need is a sequence?  Everything about this program says "using memory unnecessarily" all over it, so it is unsurprising to me that you are using a lot of memory.  And so on.  Do you have a C# expert in your organization who can review your work?

Comment: I changed a few things before i posted this.  I realize that i'm reading all the files into memory.  As stated, at the completion of reading all the files, i'm only consuming 228 MB total.  once i flatten my select many it jumps to 1.09 GB.  I was doing the dispose and clear to try to clean up some of the memory.  The ref is because of my lack of understanding with C# referencing as i'm from a C/C++ background having to explicitly handle referencing and memory.  How would you recursive add file contents to a stream?

Comment: @xtreampb: Go back farther than that. Why are you performing this hashing operation in the first place?

Comment: so i can compare if the files contained on a local computer is the same as what is on the distribution server.  This is used to determine if the files stored on the local computer needs to be updated with that on the distribution server.

Comment: @xtreampb you should probably be using a command line utility of some sort to compare whole file systems. even such a utility would not be reading all files into memory all at once.

Comment: @xtreampb: OK. You are loading in whole directories of files at once. Suppose in one directory you have files foo and bar, identical on two machines, but on one machine the operating system enumerates them in order foo, bar, and on the other, bar then foo. Is `EnumerateDirectories` guaranteed to always produce the same files *in the same order*? If not, then your hash technique fails.

Comment: @xtreampb: More generally though I don't see how what you are computing here solves your problem. The output that you need is *the minimal sequence of actions necessary to cause the two file repositories to become synchronized*. My wife used to work on Microsoft ActiveSync a decade ago and I can tell you that from dinner conversations with her, solving this problem efficiently and correctly is surprisingly difficult. My advice to you is to stop writing code and start doing literature searches on research in this area.

Comment: I can guarantee that the same operating system will be installed across all machines using these functions.  Besides that point, what would be your recommendation?  I saw below about hashing each file and storing the hash instead of the file bytes.  then collapsing the byte array list and compute the hash of this new array/list/enumerable.  This is doable but is there something better.  Also i'm still concerned with collapsing the object as it is at that point when the memory consumption spikes.

Comment: @xtreampb: Who cares if it is the same operating system?  **Does the operating system guarantee that two directories with the same files will always list them in the same order**? Your algorithm *relies* on that property; are you willing to make the correctness of your algorithm dependent on *hoping* that the operating system does what you think it should? Or should you make the correctness of your algorithm dependent on *what the operating system actually guarantees*?

Comment: @xtreampb: My more general point though is that you are attacking a problem -- machine synchronization -- that has a long history of being known to be difficult to get right. Take a step back, do some research, and find out how more experienced people have solved this problem in the past before you write more code.

Comment: and that is why I came here.  I've asked a few time what yo would recommend.  What are some resources I can use to gain further understanding of this issue.  I'm asking for guidance on where to look to gain deeper understanding of this issue.

Comment: @xtreampb: If that's why you came here then you came to the wrong place; StackOverflow is explicitly not for pointing people at off-site resources, or for doing their research for them. It's for specific problems about specific code, and we've already constructively pointed out many specific problems in your specific code.

Comment: I apologize.  I thought i could get more advice here not just specifics.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading all files into memory, and compute a hash over all files.
You have all files at the same time in memory. Thats why you run out of memory.

why not reading the files one by one and compute a hash for each file, store the single hashes in a list of hashes and compute a hash over the hashes in the end?